# Run two shortcut commands in Firefox at once

Tags: javascript, firefox, command, keyboard-shortcuts

I have two shortcuts in Firefox that I want to launch, on immediately after the other. The first one is a custom one of the actions from the Web Developer addon. The second is a simple F5 to refresh the page.

Is there a way to run both of those using only a single command or a button press? Maybe a JavaScript bookmark could?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/)** to setup multiple commands with a single keyboard shortcut.

Check this example out for the help. (It is fairly easy to do that.)

[**Multiple Commands to Single Hotkey**](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/89379-multiple-commands-to-one-hotkey/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run two Shortcuts Commands at once in Firefox.

You can use this Autohotkey Script.

```
;GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ; Chrome or Iron
;GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class IEFrame            ; Internet Explorer
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass ; FireFox
;GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow ; Edge

; Click on the keyboard Ctrl+Shift+e 
; if Firefox browser is active then execute the two Shortcuts Commands.
^+e::  

; [+ = Shift]  [! = Alt]  [^ = Ctrl]  [# = Win] 
If WinActive("ahk_group Browser")
{ 
send ^+i ;The first shortcut Command = open the inspector
sleep 150
send {f5} ;The second shortcut Command = Refresh the Page in Browser
}
return

esc::exitapp
```